# Message when session timeout

Tags: session, extjs, timeout

I have created a desktop app in ExtJs 4.2.1, and now I want to show an output message, before session timeout. 
(for example:  Session close in 5 min.)

What methods or functions should I add? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: how you are maintaining session?By last server call made or on the basis of user inactivity on the browser

Comment: By last server call made